# Integrating path of a diffusion process

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a process that satisfies the Ito diffusion process:

$$dX_t = a(X_t) dt + b(X_t) dW_t$$

I am interested in approximate numerically

$$I(\omega) = \int_0^t X_s ds$$ and eventually also

$$I' = E[I(\omega)] = E\left[\int_0^t X_s ds\right]$$

How one would go about calculating this?

**My thoughts**

I used the [Milstein method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milstein_method) to numerically approximate on path of $X$, that is I have a "function" $t \mapsto X_t$ (in reality I have only a number of points of this function)

Then the naive way would be to just use this points to calculate the integral using standard numerical approximation (probably choosing the partitions for the integral so that they coincide with the points of the function you actually have)

The problem is that $t \mapsto X_t$ is only continuos, and I am not aware of any algorithm that can bound the error term if we assume the function to be only continuos. I asked [a question about it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523928/a-bound-for-the-error-of-the-numerical-approximation-of-a-continuous-function-in), anyhow.

Can somebody help?

---

Another thought:

I know that there is the left rectangular method, that can bound the integration error using the $\alpha$-order Hölder norm. And I know that there exists a $\alpha < 1/2$ for which brownian motion is $\alpha$-Hölder, but

- Does this property extends to the general solution of a diffusion process and
- How to calculate this norm in any case?

In general it seems like a very common thing to do, yet I cannot find anything searching on the internet. But there *have* to be books or papers that talk about this

Comment: Monte Carlo integration only requires square integrability to get an error estimate of the form $\frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$, so it will work in your context. Alternately, if you prefer to have deterministic nodes, provided you have even Holder continuity, there is a nice error estimate for Gaussian quadrature. Specifically the error is on the order of $n^{-\alpha/2}$ if your functions are Holder continuous with exponent $\alpha$. I think that a better bet than *either* of these options would be to write $I(t,\omega)$ as an Ito process itself, and then simulate that (using e.g. Milstein's method).

Comment: Note that computing $E[I]$ is actually an easier problem than sampling $I$, because you can just interchange the expectation and integral: $E[I(t)]=\int_0^t E[X_s] ds$. So the only remaining question is computing $E[X_s]$ and then computing an ordinary integral. Generally $E[X_s]$ will actually be much smoother than $X_s$ itself, so this integral is quite easy to compute numerically.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your feed back and I'm sorry for the (very late) reply. I actually need to compute $E[exp(\int \rho_t dt)]$ so I think I need to use monte carlo. the problem is that monte carlo calls for $n$ random points in the interval, and I may not have $\rho_t$ in those points (milstein scheme only gives me $N$ points equally spaced in the interval). Do you think that generating the $n$ points to calculate the integral and then take a "small enough" step in the milstein scheme so that I have the funciton $\rho$ is all those points is acceptable? Would that cause problems?

Comment: Milstein's method does not require the points to be evenly spaced. It is usually stated this way but it is not at all essential. You can instead have variable step sizes in your method for computing realizations so that you get samples at the time intervals specified by the Monte Carlo procedure.

Comment: Also, just because there is the exponential does not really mean that there is any problem. In particular, $E[\exp(\int_0^t \rho_s ds)]$ is $P_t(\exp)(0)$, where $P_t$ is the semigroup of the stochastic process $Y_t = \int_0^t \rho_s ds$. This semigroup can be calculated in terms of its generator; the generator can be computed using Ito's formula. (Thankfully $\exp$ is smooth, so it is in the domain of the generator.)

Comment: @Ian Again, thanks a lot but you last comment is above my current level. (unfortunately I don't have a strong understading of stochastic processes yet; I'll study it more in depth in next courses). anyhow if you want to make an answer comprising of your previous comments I'll gladly accept it :D :D

Comment: Really, this will help you a lot, so you should try to learn it. We introduce the notion of a semigroup of a stochastic process. We can write it as $P(t,f,x)=E[f(X_t) \mid X_0=x]$. It can reasonably be defined for a quite wide class of functions $f$, but bounded continuous functions are sufficient for most purposes. Now we introduce $L(f,x)=\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}$. I wrote this without a dependence on $t$. This occurs because $P$ has the *semigroup property*, which in turn follows from the Markov property of $X_t$.

Comment: So in your case, your answer is $u(t,0)$ where $u$ satisfies the PDE $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = Lu,u(0,x)=\exp(x)$, and $L$ is the generator of the process $Y_t=\int_0^t \rho_s ds$. Note that no pathwise simulation is required, you just have to solve a PDE. In very high dimensions it might be *easier* to do pathwise simulation, but in one dimension it is definitely easier to solve the PDE.

Comment: @Ian Uhm.. and I have the process $$d\rho_t = a(\rho_t) dt + b(\rho_t)dW_t$$. Let's say that I can compute the generator of this process. Than I want the generator of the process $\int \rho_t$, so I need the generator of the process followed by $\int_0^t \rho_s ds$. I can write $$\int_0^t \rho_s ds = \int_0^t \int_0^s a(\rho_l) dl ds + \int_0^t \int_0^s b(\rho_l)dW_l ds $$. But now how to continue? Is there any relation between the generator of $\rho_t$ and $\int_0^t \rho_s ds$?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the simple fact that $\int_0^t \rho_s ds$ is not a Markov process. You could proceed using the generator of the pair $(\int_0^t \rho_s ds,\rho_t)$; I am not sure if that would help or not.